# 'Open in new tab' click on link not open href value

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue2 and I have `<a>` tag with `href='#'` and `@click.prevent="someMethod()"`.

This is working as expected in a situation when do a left click (it is calling a method), but if I do a `right click -> open in new tab`, in that case it is opening `href` value, which is wrong.

Which approach do you suggest in order to also call a `@click.prevent="someMethod()"` when opening from non-left click situations?

Comment: Why are you using an anchor tag? why not use a button? That would be the aria compliant way of doing it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is a 'company rule' that we must follow, all links must go as anchor tag

Comment: Do you just want it so that when someone right clicks on the `<a>` tag is just fires the method? You say that when you right click, and select "open in a new tab", that the behavior is wrong, but it's not clear what you think the correct behavior should be.

If you just want to control right click events, you can use `@click.right` to control right clicks explicitly.

Comment: @RobertStefanic, I need to have same behavior for all clicks (left click, ctrl + left click, command + left click as it goes for iOS, right click + open in new tab etc).
Expected behavior is that click fires method, not href value

Comment: @99Coder "Open in New Tab" should not perform the same action as a left click. Also you said this is a company policy that all *links* must be an anchor tag (good), but is this really a link in this case? It seems like a button. You can always use a button but style it as a link if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have keeped anchor link with @click.prevent + added
`:href='sameMethodAsInClickEvent()'` so now, if it will be non-left-click, it will call `href` and still it will open the right link/method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to control the behavior for all clicks, then you'll need to add more than one click event handler.

Something like this. [Here's a working JSFiddle of the code.](https://jsfiddle.net/3j9s6hcp/)

```
  <a
    href="#"
    @click.prevent="someMethod()"
    @auxclick.prevent="someMethod()"
    @contextmenu.prevent
  >
    Click Me
  </a>
</div>
```

`@click.prevent` handles left click events.

`@auxclick.prevent` handles auxclick events (i.e. non-left click events).

`@contextmenu.prevent` disables the context menu that pops up when you right click on the element.

Comment: Regarding `@contextmenu.prevent`, it should be visible and option to open `in new tab` should be active (and not to triger `href` link), no requirements to hide context menu

Comment: Short of doing something very hacky (in other words, bad) where you change the `href` of the anchor tag in a function when the contextmenu appears, and then changing it back to "#" after a certain amount of time, you can't really do that. That's just how browsers handle right clicking on `<a>` tags. I know you said that using an anchor tag is a hard requirement here, but you can't really control that. An alternative could be to make your own context menu and show that to the user when they right click on the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override the native context menu Open in New Tab behavior; it will always open the anchor's href in a new tab.

Your only options are:

- Prevent the context menu from being shown with `@contextmenu.prevent`. Not good UX.
- Prevent the context menu but instead show your own custom context menu with an Open in New Tab item which you can handle yourself.
- Use a `<button>`. This was my first thought since you don't really need an anchor here anyway because there's no real link.